# Fixed Scrolling Div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fixed

The entire left side of my website (http://www.medigapbuyersguide.com/new/) is fixed and scrolls with the screen when scrolling down. I used Jquery for this.

I have two issues;

- The left side won't stop scrolling once it hits the footer (bottom portion).
- When I resize the window, the left side moves out of place.

How do I fix these issues?

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#left-menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('#left-    menu').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#left-menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#left-menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

#left-menu { 
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width:290px;
}

#left-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 132px;
  padding-top: 19px;
}

#left-menu.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you but you need to make a few changes. There are 2 ways of fixing this:
1 - you need to wrap the side bar and the content inside a DIV and then separate them into 2 DIVS = SIDEBAR and MAINCONTENT for example. Then we can calculate.

2 - make some crazy calculation right now!

I suggest 1st to create the div containers correctly then we can calculate. Also check http://j.mp/11Mjvgk

Comment: Ok I made a div called content-wrapper, inside that the entire left side is wrapped in a div called left-menu and the right is called right-content.

Comment: Better :D Let me try something and see if it works. I will post asap.

Comment: Can you Add this to your site? http://j.mp/11Mjvgk and comment your code please. I will try to give you the final code afterwards.

Comment: Ok so I got the issue with the resizing of the window fixed. Only issue now is the overlapping of the footer.

Comment: That is the only problem but you need to make a few lines of code to make this work. Has you can see there are a few validations you need to make. It is not an easy one. portamento.js does all of this for you. You need to calculate the height of the side bar and compare it to the height of the main container while the user is scrolling down. Check the code to see how complicate this is. Last time I tried to do this own my own it take me 1 week. Check this code: http://simianstudios.com/portamento/portamento.js